# put a class in the table according to the database

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this table in phpmyadmin
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YsYj.png)
and I already have the connection and the value is stored here `$row["Risco"]`
and I have this table that are squares [squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmvvv.png)

```css
.tabela-botoes-extincao{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.espaco-botoes-extincao{
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.extincao-ativo{
    background-color: #e8bc5d;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabela-botoes-extincao">
    <tr>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Não Avaliada
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo">
            Pouco Preocupante
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Vuneravél
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Em Perigo
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Criticamente em Perigo
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Extinta na Natureza
        </th>
        <th class="espaco-botoes-extincao">
            Extinta
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then I want to put the class `extinction-active` that changes the color of the square in the corresponding square that comes from the database

the goal is to change the color according to what is received from the database and I thought about using this way and maybe using a switch but I don't know how to implement it .... I accept different proposals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already thought of a way, it gets big but it works

```html
<table class="tabela-botoes-extincao">
    <tr>
        <?php
        $nivel=$row["Risco"];
        switch ($nivel){
            case "Não Avaliada":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Pouco Preocupante":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Vuneravél":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Em Perigo":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Criticamente em Perigo":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Extinta na Natureza":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
            case "Extinta":
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Não Avaliada</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Pouco Preocupante</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Vuneravél</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Criticamente em Perigo</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao'>Extinta na Natureza</th>";
                echo "<th class='espaco-botoes-extincao extincao-ativo'>Extinta</th>";
                break;
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```